# Change translation based on genders - react-i18next

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-i18next

How can I change the translations based on gender?

I know there's a [Select](https://react.i18next.com/misc/using-with-icu-format) component where we can switch translations based on a key, but that isn't the case since the translations have to be passed hardcoded

For now, what i did was to create a new key for every gender, but every time that i add a new role, it will need two keys:

```
  "Female Backend Engineer": "Engenheira Backend",
  "Male Backend Engineer": "Engenheiro Backend",
  "Female Backend Intern": "Estagiária Backend",
  "Male Backend Intern": "Estagiário Backend",
  "Female Fullstack Engineer": "Engenheira Fullstack",
  "Male Fullstack Engineer": "Engenheiro Fullstack",
  "Female Frontend Engineer": "Engenheira Frontend",
  "Male Frontend Engineer": "Engenheiro Frontend",
  "Female Frontend Intern": "Estagiária Frontend",
  "Male Frontend Intern": "Estagiário Frontend",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i18next has a context feature: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/context